# Kotlin SAM Runtime Error: NoSuchMethodError: No static method

Tags: kotlin

Today I ran into a really strange runtime error while developing kotlin / android that involves SAM conversions and sub classing.

Here's a minimal example of pure java + kotlin. Here are two java classes:

```
public class A {
    public interface I {
        public void f();
    }

    public I i;
}

public class B extends A {}
```

And here is a kotlin main function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    A().i = B.I {}
}
```

This code compiles fine but at run time I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: B.I(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)LA$I;
        at MainKt.main(Main.kt:2)
```

Now, this is already bad -- if code like this does not work (it never will I guess) the compiler should raise an error. But at least one could say that it is bad idea to reference to the interface `I` via the subclass `B` instead of the place of definition `A` (i.e., `A.I`).

It's less clear though, if this code is in a sub class of `B` where I can reference `I` directly using `I`:

```
class C: B {
    constructor() {
        this.i = I {}
    }
}
```

So my questions would be:

1. Why is this behavior happening at all?
2. If it is happening, why is the compiler not raising an error already?

PS: In android the error message looks similar to this, which is even more confusing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method OnFocusChangeListener(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;)Landroid/view/View$OnFocusChangeListener; in class Landroid/widget/LinearLayout; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.widget.LinearLayout' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
```

Comment: It seems that frontend recognized `B.I {}` as a function call with lambda argument outside of parenthesis. I bet this is a result of failing assumptions. Verifier (or whatsoever they name it) did found `B.I` denotes a valid SAM interface through some name registry that follow the JLS (allow supertype static members referenced through subtypes). The compiler backend, whose name system don't follow JLS (because kotlin doesn't have static), however didn't found `B.I` *declared* in `B.java`, so it expect it to be a function call. This is just a random guess though.

Comment: Conclusion of my guess: the compiler frontend and backend have different policy regarding *whether supertype static members referenced through subtypes is allowed*. You should file a issue on [kotlin youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18745

Answer (score 0):

Define main method as static like-

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        A().i = B.I {}
    }
}
```